# Lithium PHP Framework - CLI generators and naming conventions

Tags: php, lithium

I need some guidance on Lithium Framework:

1. Is there any code generators? E.g. CLI model generator? Is there any
   documentation on this topic?
2. What are naming conventions for models? Some tutorials and pieces of
   documentation say that a name should be plural but in
   "manual\working-with-data\relationships.wiki" names are singular.
3. How to name transitional tables (models)? "Posts", "Tags" and ...
   PostTags?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lithium has a cli tool. It's called 'li3' and you can find it under the lithium/console directory. It creates models, views, tests, and what not. As for naming your models and tables, plural names are the convention. Posts, Tags, and PostTags as you mentioned -- although there is no HABTM support in li3.

You should checkout the manual available at http://li3.me/docs/manual. It's official documentation source, and is based off the more up-to-date li3 manual repository at https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/manual.